# Conexión en PHP para base de datos en AWS

Tags: php, aws

espero se encuentren muy bien.

Actualmente tengo problemas en mi conexión a la base de datos con AWS.

Tengo mi sistema subido en Cpanel y actualmente estoy intentando conectar el archivo de conexión de mi sistema que esta en Cpanel a una base de datos que esta en AWS, el problema es que no se logra conectar y aun no se cual pueda ser el problema.

Esta es la conexión que estoy usando pero aun así siempre me arroja el mensaje: No se puede conectar a la base de datos.

```
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("aio-tst.cxabxn9cyhs0.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com","admin","estanoes","AWS");

    if($mysqli->connect_errno){
            die("No se puede conectar a la base de datos");
    }

    die("Conectado a la base de datos");
    
?>
```

Por otro lado si intento conectarme por ejemplo desde Navicat si me deja con los mismos datos, solo que le agrego el puerto: 3306.

No se si alguien se ha topado con este problema, cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar podria ser de gran utilidad.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Y si le pasas el puerto al [constructor de mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php)? Ya que identificaste la diferencia, podrías probar...

Comment: Si es un compartido pregunta si tienen abierto el puerto TCP numero 3306 de salida en su firewall, o intenta realizar una conexion a ese puerto desde el terminal de cpanel, si es que tienes acceso a el, mediante un simple `telnet aio-tst.cxabxn9cyhs0.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com 3306` y ver si te contesta algo o se queda colgado. Desde mi máquina local se queda colgado, por lo tanto seguramente en tu AWS debes indicarle que deje pasar la IP del servidor de cPanel tambien pues más bien pinta eso el error.

Comment: Hola @estrada, al parecer el problema que tienes es que el puerto para la conexión con el servidor 3306 está cerrado y no se puede acceder a él. Primero verifica que el puerto de conexión remota sea el 3306 y segundo verifica que este abierto en el firewall. Esta es la prueba que hice con los datos que colocaste.  `aio-tst.cxabxn9cyhs0.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306 port is closed` y se puede observar que está cerrado

Comment: Ha añadido al rol IAM de tu servicio permisos de lectura y escritura sobre el servicio que está ejecutando la base de datos?

Comment: Hola muy buenas tardes, muchas gracias por su ayuda.